# Webassessor Email Address & Login change

Tags: email, login, address

I found links to this question but was not able to post my query on the same link and was also confused by the existing answer.

On the **Webassessor --> Edit Profile** page there are 3 email address fields:

1. Email Address
2. Email Address associated with your Salesforce account
3. Webassessor login (which is also an email address)
   In my case all of these are my official company email id (eg: myfname.mylname@mycompany.com)

How do I get all of these to be updated to my personal email address (at both Salesforce & Kryterion) without impacting my certification data/account? What exactly do I have to do?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can [open a case](http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case) with Salesforce University

Answer (score 6):

I've had to do this. Whilst you can change most details on the Edit Profile page, your e-mail address is something you can't change. You'll need to contact them directly, you can use ktnsupport@kryteriononline.com to ask them to change those details.

> How do I get all of these to be updated to my personal email address (at both Salesforce & Kryterion) without impacting my certification data/account?

For clarity on this, your Salesforce and Kryterion aren't one and the same, they're totally seperate. Changing your Kryterion address will not affect your certifications. What it will do, however, on Salesforce's [Verification](http://certification.salesforce.com/verification) site is change lookups to your new address. So if someone is used to typing your.name@company.com and you change it to your17name@gmail.com, they'll find nothing for the former but your certs for the latter.

**Tl;dr:**

To change your e-mail on Kryterion, you have to contact them.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you Dan & Robin !! This worked for me.
ktnsupport@kryteriononline.com changed my Webassessor login to my personal email Id.
After changing the following emails in the Webassessor profile - 1. Email Address 2. Email Address associated with your Salesforce account, I did check the Verification section on certification.salesforce.com
It did not show my certs against the personal email Id. So I opened a case with Salesforce certification team. They have now tagged my cert records to my personal email instead of the company email as was earlier.

Comment: Rather than posting a thank you answer, please accept the answer which helped you resolve your issue.